# AttributeError when clicking on new button added by custom module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to add a new button on a res.partner form view (base.view_partner_form) by custom module to open a new browser tab, but I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 540, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 577, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 313, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 310, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 806, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 406, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'res.partner' object has no attribute 'g_search'
```

The button appears but I am getting stuck with that error. These are my files contents:

**mymodule.py**

```
import openerp
from openerp.osv import fields, osv, orm
from openerp import models

class cant_neg_gs(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.multi
    def g_search(self):
        res = {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': 'http://www.myurl.com',
            'target': 'new',
        } 
    return res
```

**mymodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="gs_cant_neg_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.cant_neg_gs.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='title']" position="after">
                    <button string="Buscar empresa" type="object" name="g_search" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**__init__.py**

```
import cant_neg_gs
```

**__openerp__.py**

```
{
    'name': 'My Module,
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'summary': 'Summary',
    'sequence': 2,
    'description': """

Info
====================================================
More info

Things :
-------------------------------
* Button
""",
    'author': 'Name',
    'website': 'https://example.com',
    'depends': ['base',],
    'data': [
        'cant_neg_gs.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have import **import cant_neg_gs** class name, but you must import file. name not a class name Ex-: **import mymodule**.

There is one more issue in you code, you can follow below code.

```
from openerp import models,fields,api
class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit="res.partner"

    @api.multi
    def g_search(self):
        res = {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': 'http://www.myurl.com',
            'target': 'new',
        } 
        return res
```

In your file **api** is not imported, you have used **@api.multi** that's why you must import api.

This may help you.